# Getting Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function in ThemeProvider.js of Bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

Ran ">npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap"

Imported the Button Component from Bootstrap and added to the page. I am getting the below error.

My package.json has below entries for bootstrap along with other entries for react.

```
"react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.14",
"bootstrap": "^4.3.1",

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ToggleButtonGroup from 'react-bootstrap/ToggleButtonGroup';
import ToggleButton from 'react-bootstrap/ToggleButton';

class MyButtonComponent extends Component {

    render() {
        let value  =1;
        return (

           <ToggleButtonGroup type="checkbox" value={value} >
             <ToggleButton value={1}>Option 1</ToggleButton>
             <ToggleButton value={2}>Option 2</ToggleButton>
             <ToggleButton value={3}>Option 3</ToggleButton>
           </ToggleButtonGroup>

        );
    }
}

export default MyButtonComponent ;
```

---

Error log

```
ThemeProvider.js:29 Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at useBootstrapPrefix (VM106126 ThemeProvider.js:29)
    at eval (VM106134 ButtonGroup.js:29)
    at updateForwardRef (VM105779 react-dom.development.js:13046)
    at beginWork (VM105779 react-dom.development.js:13837)
    at performUnitOfWork (VM105779 react-dom.development.js:15864)
    at workLoop (VM105779 react-dom.development.js:15903)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (VM105779 react-dom.development.js:100)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (VM105779 react-dom.development.js:138)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (VM105779 react-dom.development.js:187)
    at replayUnitOfWork (VM105779 react-dom.development.js:15311)
```

Comment: What version of react and react-dom do you have

Comment: below are my react js versions 
"react": "16.4.2",
  "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.14",
  "react-dom": "16.4.2",
  "react-moment": "^0.9.2",
  "react-pagination-js": "^2.0.0",
  "react-redux": "5.0.7",
  "react-render-html": "0.6.0",
  "react-router": "4.3.1",
  "react-router-dom": "4.3.1",
  "react-toastify": "^5.4.0",

Comment: @roopa the `react-bootstrap` is using the React Context API which is not introduced in the React 16.4.2 you need to upgrade to at least 16.8.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`React bootstrap v1.0.0-beta.14` has a peerDependency on react and react dom and requires versions `>=16.8.0` which support hooks which is why you get this error

```
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": ">=16.8.0",
    "react-dom": ">=16.8.0"
  },
```

Upgrade you versions of react and react-dom from 16.4.0 to 16.8.0 or the latest version to solve the above error

Comment: Thanks Shubham after upgrading react versions to latest it worked

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong in your code so I tried it on code sandbox and I am getting the output correctly, the error may have been caused by some other component:

```
import ToggleButtonGroup from "react-bootstrap/ToggleButtonGroup";
import ToggleButton from "react-bootstrap/ToggleButton";

class MyButtonComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    let value = 1;
    return (
      <ToggleButtonGroup type="checkbox" value={value}>
        <ToggleButton value={1}>Option 1</ToggleButton>
        <ToggleButton value={2}>Option 2</ToggleButton>
        <ToggleButton value={3}>Option 3</ToggleButton>
      </ToggleButtonGroup>
    );
  }
}

export default MyButtonComponent;
```

Here is what the output is:

[image]

Here is the Link to CodeSandBox Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-leaf-xj8ix

Comment: Thanks Harish. The issue was with the react version being old. After updating to latest even i was able to get the same result.